# Deallocate Elastic Search Memory after uninstall

Tags: elasticsearch

I am on Windows 10 and I installed ElasticSearch from msi package and installed it as a service. I configured 2GB memory for its cluster and nodes while installing.
[image]

Now I want to uninstall it completely and deallocate all the memory, I uninstalled it from `Add or Remove Programs` and also made sure that I don't have any service named `Elasticsearch` in `services.msc`.

Even after uninstalling I see in my Task manager that 2GB ram is still being used and I believe its because of Elasticsearch.

[image]

How can I deallocate that memory? I have also tried restarting my computer multiple times but still 2GB memory is still allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Task manager doesn't show usefull info, try to download https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer
run it as administrator and discover dllhost.exe process - try to understand which dll is consuming resources.

Comment: I tried but I cant see any child dll under dllhost.exe process